# Comparing 3 colums in GridView, if all match, set background of row to green

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am writing a page where I am listing data in a GridView, based on several databases. All databases have the field "Location" (nvarchar). 
If this field is identical, I would like to mark the row in Green colour.

Do not have much knowledge in ASP/VB, any help is appreciated.

Code example below is just a try, not functioning/or complete at this stage.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataSourceID="DSViewAll">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location1" HeaderText="Location1" SortExpression="Location1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location2" HeaderText="Location2" SortExpression="Location2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location3" HeaderText="Location3" SortExpression="Location3" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>


Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound _
        (sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) _
        Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If e.Column.FieldName = "Location1" Then
                    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
                    Dim val1 As String = (view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns("Location1")))
                    Dim val2 As String = (view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns("Location2")))
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = If(val1 = val2, Color.Green, e.Appearance.BackColor)
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Depending on the length of your list, you might try another approach.   Make sure your datasource has a flag for identical values.   Using this flag you then change the color to green.   Otherwise you will have to loop over all your columns to find identical values.   This might slow down the loading of your page.

Comment: The GridView only displays 100-200 rows at maximum.

Comment: What is your datasource ? I would add a column named e.g. 'Identical' to your datasource.  Using Linq you can then update the 'identical' column.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 in the background, SqlDataSource.

Comment: Its currently a view binding the data from the 3 databases together, see example: 
SELECT        dbo.DB1.Location1, dbo.DB1.SomeFieldMatchingDB2, dbo.DB2.Location2, dbo.DB2.SomeFieldMatchingDB1, dbo.DB2.SomeFieldMatchingDB3, dbo.DB3.Location3, dbo.DB3.dbo.DB2.SomeFieldMatchingDB2
FROM            dbo.DB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DB2 ON dbo.DB1.SomeFieldMatchingDB2 = dbo.DB2.SomeFieldMatchingDB1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DB3 ON dbo.DB1.SomeFieldMatchingDB3 = dbo.DB3.SomeFieldMatchingDB1

And, yes, I am able to edit the view, or make an stored procedure if so.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your query : SELECT IFF(dbo.DB1.Location1 = dbo.DB2.Location2 AND dbo.DB2.Location2 = dbo.DB3.Location3) AS Identical, ....

Then in code behind

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  'the cell where the field with the name "Identical" is shown
  If e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "True" Then
      e.Row.BackColor = Color.Green
  End If
End If
```

Or without changing the query

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
'the cells where the fields with the names "Location1", "Location2" and "Location3" are shown
   If e.Row.Cells(1).Text = e.Row.Cells(2).Text AndAlso e.Row.Cells(2).Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text   Then
      e.Row.BackColor = Color.Green
   End If
End If
```

Comment: How about an `AndAlso`

Comment: @Mary of course, thx.  Used to c# (where short-circuiting should not be specified).  I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean by "where short-circuiting should not be specified" Don't you use && and || for AndAlso and OrElse in C#?

Comment: Yes we use '&&' for 'AndAlso', but I was not aware the VB.net 'And' did not include short-circuiting.  Is there a C# equivalent for the VB.net  'And' ?

Comment: In C# the logical And is & (a single ampersand) From MS docs "For bool operands, the & operator computes the logical AND of its operands"  Same idea for | in C# , Or in vb.net. "For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands;"

Comment: Perfect, bottom example with modification made my day! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Stian if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.